# Função JavaScript retorna NaN enquanto develira retornar um Número

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Meu objetivo: fazer uma calculadora IMC.
Para isso, recebo o valor de "peso" e de "altura". Executo o cálculo e deveria retornar um console.log com o valor do IMC.

O PROBLEMA: o retorno do console.log está NaN.
Não sei o que está faltando no meu código. Preciso de Ajuda.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', pegaValores)  

function pegaValores(){
    var altura = document.getElementsByClassName('.inputAltura').value;
    var peso = document.getElementsByClassName('inputPeso').value;
  
    altura = parseFloat(altura);
    peso = parseFloat(peso);
    
    console.log(calculaimc());

}

function calculaimc(altura,peso){
    var imc = peso / (altura * altura);
    imc = parseFloat(imc);
    return imc
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculadora IMC</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main class="container">
        <h1 class="Titulo">Calculadora IMC</h1>
        <form class="containerForm">
            <div class="peso">
                <label class="labelPeso">Qual é o seu peso?</label>
                <input type="text" class="inputPeso">
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="altura">
                <label class="labelAltura"> Qual é a sua altura?</label>
                <input type="text" class="inputAltura">
                <br>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn">Calcular</button>
        </form>
    </main>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tem vários erros no seu código. **1°** O `document.getElementsByClassName` por padrão retorna um array de elementos Html com aquela classe fornecida, mesmo que só tenha 1 elemento com aquela classe, então teria que ser **`document.getElementsByClassName('inputAltura')[0].value`** pra pegar o valor. **2°** não precisa do ponto `getElementsByClassName('.inputAltura')` o comando já sabe que tem que buscar por classes no Html. **3°** Não passou os valores como parâmetro na chamada da função `calculaimc()`.

Answer (score -2):

Primeira coisa, quando você usa o .getElementsByClassName, ele retornaum array com todos os elementos que possuem aquela classe. Como não teriam mais elementos com aquela classe, eu substitui ele por um id.
Segunda coisa, a função calculaimc precisa de dois parâmetros, altura e peso. Quando vc chama a função dentro daquele console log, você não passa nenhum parâmetro. O certo seria `console.log(calculaimc(altura, peso))`.
E por último, para o calculo ficar correto, a altura precisa estar em metros, então eu adicionei uma divisão por 100, pra ficar correto.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', pegaValores)  

function pegaValores(){
    const altura = Number(document.getElementById('inputAltura').value)/100;
    const peso = Number(document.getElementById('inputPeso').value);
    
    console.log(calculaimc(altura, peso));

}

function calculaimc(altura,peso){
    var imc = peso / (altura * altura);
    return imc.toFixed(1)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculadora IMC</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main class="container">
        <h1 class="Titulo">Calculadora IMC</h1>
        <form class="containerForm">
            <div class="peso">
                <label class="labelPeso">Qual é o seu peso?</label>
                <input type="text" id="inputPeso">
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="altura">
                <label class="labelAltura"> Qual é a sua altura?</label>
                <input type="text" id="inputAltura">
                <br>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn">Calcular</button>
        </form>
    </main>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show! Valeu pela explicação! Agora entendi!